# Объявление неизвестного типа в интерфейсе

Tags: android, java, классы, ооп

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите пожалуйста решение такой задачи:

```
interface IModel{
  public int getId();
}

class modelA implement IModel{
  private int id;
  public int getId(){
    return id;
  }
}

class modelB implement IModel{
  private String id;
  public String getId(){
    return id;
  }
}
```

Как мне в интерфейсе сказать, что `getId()` может возвращать как `int`, так и `String`?

Comment: Как код, который будет взаимодействовать с интерфейсом поймет чего ему ожидать- строку или число ?  Значит что-то Вы неверно продумали в своей объектной модели.

Comment: каким-то грязным кодом пахнет. Что вам мешает сделать два интерфейса? Ведь это по сути разные методы, несмотря на одинаковость их сигнатур

Comment: Да, что-то не вяжется. Дизайн и правда с запашком...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, имеет смысл сделать два интерфейса, один из которых будет содержать int getId(), а второй String getId(). Если же помимо этого метода интерфейс должен содержать еще какие-то другие, то имеет смысл сделать один общий интерфейс с общими методами, а от него наследовать два интерфейса-потомка, у одного из которых будет метод int getId(), а у другого string getId(). Я надеюсь, Java позволяет наследовать интерфейсы друг от друга? Если же не позволяет, то можно вынести все общие методы в один интерфейс, а два отличающихся разнести по отдельным. Не думаю, что введение одного-двух новых интерфейсов будет трагедией, особенно на фоне предлагавшихся ранее манипуляций с приведением и/или выдиранием нужного значения из строки

Comment: уважаемый мистер Анонимный Минусатор, надеюсь, вы не поленились поставить аж 6(!) минусов на 6 различных моих ответов. Неужели вы узнали, что я 15 лет назад не вернул в школьную библиотеку книжку "Как строить скворечники"?

Answer (score 6):

```
interface IModel<T> {
    public T getId();
}

class modelA implements IModel<Integer> {
    private int id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

class modelB implements IModel<String> {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: как то совсем все забыли про шаблоны...

Answer (score 1):

```
interface IModel
{
    public Object getId();
}
```

Для классов **Integer** и **String** класс **Object** - базовый, поэтому можно сделать так. Потом достаточно будет приводить возвращаемое значение к нужному

Comment: что в этом предложении не так? прокомментируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: ой ой ой, а потом как выскочит ClassCastException... или придётся проверять instanceof , что тоже долговато. лучше окнечно прикрутить два метода в интерфейс , кажждый из которых возвращает свой тип